# Role Tailored Client register custom page

Tags: dynamics-nav

I'm working with Dynamics Nav 2009 R2, I just created a new page object `50011 Shipment Types`, but it does not appear in the Role Tailored Client, if I search for `Shipment Types` I don't get any results. The page is also not accessible via the menu tree on the left.

I assume that I somehow need to register this new page to the Role Tailored client, and assign it to some department in the roles tree on the left. I can't find any documentation that explains how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a new page you should add it to the menu suite. 
You should open the classic client, go to the object designer (SHFT + F12) and edit the following menu suite: 1090 - Dept - Company.

If it isn't there, you should add it. 
After this your new page will be accessible in the RTC.